# Using IF to Place A Value in A Different Cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Is it possible to do something like the following?

```
=IF(A1=0, Place "Yes" in B2, Do nothing)
```

I was considering using `=OFFSET` somehow, but I'm really not sure how I would implement it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in cell B2 put

```
=IF(A1=0,"yes","")
```

Comment: Can you expand on this answer? Maybe include *what* this does, how to formulate it for other uses, etc?

Comment: the example does EXACTLY what the requestor asked.  As pointed out in another answer, a formula only determines the value of the cell that contains it.  That said the =if() function is generally =if(condition,value if true,value if false) however the 2nd and 3rd arguments could be formulas rather than simply values.

Comment: Great! Can you use the [edit] function to add that information in? It will help make this a much better answer, and help the OP as well as other visitors. Thanks!

Comment: @Tyson I think you have done enough justice with your answer. Should the OP require more help, he should use "F1" function in excel. Nonetheless, there is this official microsoft site which returns the same thing @ http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/if-function-HP010342586.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The value of `B2` must be set by a formula in `B2`. A formula only (directly) determines the value of the cell that contains it.